# How to get the streetname and city when user fills in zip code

Tags: javascript, web

I just took a look at [www.wehkamp.nl](http://wehkamp.nl) (dutch only). When you try to make an account you can fill in your zip code (postcode) and it will automatically give you your city and street name. I knew this would be possible because most streets have it's own zip code. I have found some examples of automatically filling in country and city name when a user fills in his zip code. But none of street name + city name.

This is what Wehkamp returns when I fill in a zip code.[image]

The bottom text is even telling the user that housenumber 139 does not exist on the filled in zip code.

Does anyone know if there is a special technique for this?

Comment: Why not try the Postal code database, Or use a Postal code API like: https://www.postcodeapi.nu/#developers

Comment: You basically need a service that you can query for this data.  Postal services, mapping services, etc. might have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not that hard to do. What they use is a postal code database or a postal code API. these options have thing in there like the start and end of the house numbers in that postal code area. 
They also store what street that is associated to it and what city. I can see that you are Dutch so I'm guessing that you want the Dutch database.

[Here](http://www.sqlblog.nl/nederlandse-postcodetabel-sql-script-voor-import/) is a link for a free SQL(not MySQL) database.

[Here](https://github.com/apiwise/postcodeapi) is a link to the a service that sells the API.

[Here](https://services.postcode.nl/adresdata) is a link to buy the database with updates.